# How can I limit my powerset function?

Tags: c#, optimization, powerset

I found a powerset function from a StackOverflow Post:

```
    public static T[][] FastPowerSet<T>(T[] seq)
    {
        var powerSet = new T[1 << seq.Length][];
        powerSet[0] = new T[0]; // starting only with empty set
        for (int i = 0; i < seq.Length; i++)
        {
            var cur = seq[i];
            int count = 1 << i; // doubling list each time
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                var source = powerSet[j];
                var destination = powerSet[count + j] = new T[source.Length + 1];
                for (int q = 0; q < source.Length; q++)
                    destination[q] = source[q];
                destination[source.Length] = cur;
            }
        }
        return powerSet;
    }
```

But I am not interested in the entire powerset. It uses too much memory, is limited to the maxvalue of integer, and takes too long. Imagine I have an unlimited length string that I'm taking the powerset of, I couldn't store it. I only want 10 values that are located 25% of the way through the powerset.

For instance, if I send an array of 22 values to the powerset function:

```
var toTakePowerSetOf = {3,-3,39,-39,392,-392,3920,-3920, 9, -9, 92, -92, 920, -920, 9203, -9203, 2, -2, 20, -20, 203, -203}
```

I normally get a powerset of 4194304 elements. But I only care about the values at index  @ 1049089/4194304 which is {3, -9, 203} . How can I edit the fast powerset function to use unlimited precision, go to a specific index, and only store ~10 values.

The index is calculated as 2^n/4 where n is the number of elements in the toTakePowerSetOf. For my example there are 22 elements: 2^22=4194304 . 4194304/4 = 1048576 . The actual value I was seeking is at 1049089 which is 513 away. In my question I said I would like to check the surrounding 10 values, but I guess  I should really say I'd like to check about 513 values (.0122 %) of numbers around it.

This algorithm I'm trying to use may lead to faster factoring, but I need to find out if its the case that factors always appear near 25% of the way through the powerset. It may not make much sense, but if it works I'll share it with you and we can solve P=NP lol

Comment: What is "near 25%"? Obviously you can change the limits of the outer loop to extract any part of the powerset.

Comment: The problem is when the powerset length is greater than the max integer value. It's not obvious to me.

Comment: You could upgrade to an `ulong`, or use that the upper bits are constrained by the range you're extracting.

Comment: Trying to assume the powerset length is so long the index of the 25 percent value is greater than ulong max  value. I feel like I shouldn't need to iterate I should just be able to know what the one value is

Comment: Ok so you want to convert just *one* index to the corresponding item from the powerset? That's just the index itself, where the k'th bit indicates the presence of the k'th item from the original set.

Comment: That's also obvious when you don't write it in decimal, for example 1049089=0x00100201, now it is clear which items are in the corresponding set.

Comment: Will I run out of bits with this algorithm?

Comment: Not if you use something large to store the bits, say an `int[]` .. that makes doing computations with the index trickier (not the part where you convert it to a set though), but it's not that big a deal. It's just reimplementing `BigInteger` for C# 2 really.

Comment: Would like to see an implementation of that

Comment: It would help if you explain how you want to compute the index itself

Comment: @harold updated please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the given FastPowerSet algorithm is that you need to calculate all the preceding power sets for a new one. Another Algo is presentend on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for power sets.

Here is a short implementation:

```
    public static T[][] FastPowerSet2<T>(T[] seq)
    {
        var powerSet = new T[1 << seq.Length][];
        powerSet[0] = new T[0]; // starting only with empty set
        for (uint i = 1; i < powerSet.Length; i++)
        {
            powerSet[i] = PowerSetItem(i, seq, powerSet.Length);
        }
        return powerSet;
    }

    private static T[] PowerSetItemBig<T>(BigInteger neededSetIndex, T[] p)
    {
        byte[] neededSetBytes = neededSetIndex.ToByteArray();
        BitArray b = new BitArray(neededSetBytes);
        return p.Take(b.Length).Where((s, j) =>  b[j]).ToArray();
    }

    private static T[] PowerSetItem<T>(uint powersetIndex, T[] sequence, int powersetLength)
    {
        BitArray b = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(powersetIndex));
        if (b.Length < powersetLength)
        {
            var prefix = new BitArray(powersetLength - b.Length);
            b = Append(prefix, b);
        }

        return sequence.Where((s, j) => b[j]).ToArray();
    }
    public static BitArray Append(BitArray current, BitArray after)
    {
        var bools = new bool[current.Count + after.Count];
        current.CopyTo(bools, 0);
        after.CopyTo(bools, current.Count);
        return new BitArray(bools);
    }
```

With these functions, you also have the possibility to generate the specific powerset item with:

```
int[] P = { 3, -3, 39, -39, 392, -392, 3920, -3920, 9, -9, 92, -92, 920, -920, 9203, -9203, 2, -2, 20, -20, 203, -203 };
var p1049089 = PowerSetItem(1049089, P, (2^P.Length));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", p1049089));
```

The BigInteger version works with

```
var p1049089 = PowerSetItemBig(new BigInteger(1049089), P);
```

NB: I took some shortcuts with linq, and omitted some bound checks on incoming arrays, but this will work for this specific usecase

Comment: WOW THIS IS AMAZING. I enter a set with 340,000 and it gets the 1049089 index instantly! Only flaw is I'd like to get the 2^(340000)/4 index which is too massive to store in uint. This implementation would be perfect it used BigIntegers and unlimited precision

Comment: I added a BigInteger implementation, but lacking an UnitTest to validate if it's correct in all cases.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! You Rock! Will be in contact if the factoring algorithm is as great as I think it is lol

Answer (score 1):

My solution gets you the sets around the 25% index. Both sets after that index and before that index.

My solution is not limited to the integer sizes and does not use bit arrays.

It will handle extremely long sequences. All that's needed is the context size (513 in your case) to be not extremely big.

Here is the explanation of the code:

So, you want to see some forward and backward "context" around the power set at 25% index (I'll call it "central").

The set at the 25% index is a consists of a single item. That's because 2^n/4 = 1 << (n-1-2)
    0000000000100.....

When we go forward from this set/number we are basically repeating the same first 513 power sets, but with the central item included:

```
0000000000100..... = +0 context = powerSet[0] U { seq[central] }
1000000000100..... = +1 context = powerSet[1] U { seq[central] }
0100000000100..... = +2 context = powerSet[2] U { seq[central] }
1100000000100..... = +3 context = powerSet[3] U { seq[central] }
0010000000100..... = +4 context = powerSet[4] U { seq[central] }
```

When we go backwards the numbers behave somewhat similiar, but the bits look reversed:

```
1111111111000..... = -1 context = { seq[0], seq[1], ..., seq[central - 1] } \ powerSet[0]
0111111111000..... = -2 context = { seq[0], seq[1], ..., seq[central - 1] } \ powerSet[1]
1011111111000..... = -3 context = { seq[0], seq[1], ..., seq[central - 1] } \ powerSet[2]
0011111111000..... = -4 context = { seq[0], seq[1], ..., seq[central - 1] } \ powerSet[3]
1101111111000..... = -5 context = { seq[0], seq[1], ..., seq[central - 1] } \ powerSet[4]
```

By combining the backward context with forward context we get the full [-514 .. +513] context

Here is the code that solves your problem:

```
    public static T[][] PartialPowerSet<T>(T[] seq, int forwardContextSize) {
        int n = seq.Length;
        int centralItemIndex = n - 2; //=log2(2^n/4)
        int numberOfItemsForContext = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(forwardContextSize, 2));

        var smallContextSeq = seq.Take(numberOfItemsForContext).ToArray();

        var smallContextPowerSet = FastPowerSet(smallContextSeq);
        smallContextPowerSet = smallContextPowerSet.Take(forwardContextSize + 1).ToArray();

        var forwardContextTemplateItems = new[] { seq[centralItemIndex] }; //To get forward context we're adding (union) the small context items
        var forwardContextItems = smallContextPowerSet.Select(s => s.Concat(forwardContextTemplateItems).ToArray());

        var backwardContextTemplateItems = seq.Take(centralItemIndex - 1).ToList(); //To get backward context we're removing (minus) the small context items from the set of all items up to, but not including the central item
        var backwardContextItems = smallContextPowerSet.Reverse().Select(s => backwardContextTemplateItems.Except(s).ToArray()); //Getting sets for c-513, c-512, ...., c-1. That's why we reverse the order of the smallContextPowerSet.

        return backwardContextItems.Concat(forwardContextItems).ToArray();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var toTakePowerSetOf = new[] { 3, -3, 39, -39, 392, -392, 3920, -3920, 9, -9, 92, -92, 920, -920, 9203, -9203, 2, -2, 20, -20, 203, -203 };

        var res = PartialPowerSet(toTakePowerSetOf, 513);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", res[513 + 1 + 513])); //Prints "3,-9,203"
    }
```

Prints 3,-9,203

Comment: I'm confused how you get the "context" is 513. Could you explain this a little further? Also anyway to make forwardContextSize data type a BigInteger so I can use this for unlimited precision?

Comment: >"how you get the "context" is 513". It's in your own question: "I'd like to check about 513 values (.0122 %) of numbers around it.".

Comment: >"make forwardContextSize data type a BigInteger"? I'm confused. This contradicts what you've asked. You asked to see a small range of sets around 25%. Do you want 4 billion+ range now? I do not think so.

Comment: Ahhh your comments clear up my confusion! Thank you for this genious code!